# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation tablename does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I tried get data from postgresql database, but receive this exception.

I read some alternatives, but not working for me.

```
String sql="select description from job;"
//String sql="select description from public.job;"
//String sql="select description from public.\"job\";"
//String sql="select description from \"public\".\"job\";"
//String sql="select description from \"public\".job;"
...
Statement st =  myconnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql); // throws exception
```

After execute next script I receive:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
order by table_schema, table_name;
```

Result:

```
table_catalog|table_schema|table_name|...
--Others rows
postgres|public|job|
postgres|public|job|
--Others rows
```

PostgresSQL version
PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Any idea? Thanks

Edit:

Exception

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation «job» does not exist
  Position: 25
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2497)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2233)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:311)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:274)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:225)
    ...`

Comment: Can you provide the exception you got ?

Comment: Yes, post edited!

Comment: You might not be connected to the postgres schema. Can you provide your string connection ?

Comment: Are you share that "job" table is on the public schema?

Comment: @NaorLevi yes, Check my post on "Result" section.

Comment: Do you have a client for Postgres? psql or pgadmin to see if the database and the schema exist?

Comment: Yes, from Laragon.